# Invalid argument 'NaN' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Tags: angular

In some instances of an AJAX request I am getting a string as a response instead of a number. This causes my Angular2 pipe to break.

{{stat | number:'2.1-2'}}

Is there a way to disable or change the pipe if a string is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need an additional function for this.

See this plunker for a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/7eVp2Z99Z47PBWp3eNW4?p=preview

```
import {Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'myNumber' })
export class MyNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform (value: any, args: string) {
    let pipe = new DecimalPipe();
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : +value;
    return pipe.transform(value, args);
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      {{getNumber('3') | number:'2.1-2'}}
      <br />
      {{getNumber(12) | number:'2.1-2'}}
      <br />
      {{getNumber('NaN') | number:'2.1-2'}}
      <br />
      <br />

      {{'3' | myNumber:'2.1-2'}}
      <br />
      {{12 | myNumber:'2.1-2'}}
      <br />
      {{'NaN' | myNumber:'2.1-2'}}
      <br />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  getNumber(val: any) {
    if (isNaN(val)) return 0;
    return +val;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyNumberPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Or create your own `Pipe`..

Comment: ah - I guess I should have said the server response is coming back with NaN  in a string.

Comment: What should happen in this case? Use zero? Hide that element?

Comment: Displaying a zero in this instance would be fine.

Comment: actually the DecimalPipe is asking for _lang param, is there a way to get the current one?

Answer (score 0):

Solved similar situation just using ternary operator:

```
{{stat ? stat : 0}}
```

Plz note that I was receiving **undefined**, not a string. 
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular 16+, but try piping like this if the value is already calculated as a percentage:

{{value>0? value : ''}}%

Only the % should show if the value is NaN%, without any console log errors.

Comment: Nowdeen had the ternary operator. :)